# Signing soap header

Tags: php, web-services, soap, digital-signature

I started studying web services between bank and a client and I run into a wall when it came to signing a SOAP. What I need should look something like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:cor="http://bxd.fi/CorporateFileService" xmlns:mod="http://model.bxd.fi" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="CertId-9502902" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            MIID…/DnjbkAZBo7vsj78zzdk7KNliBIqBcIszdJ3dEHRWSI7FspRxyiR0NDm4lpyLwFtfw=
        </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <ds:Signature Id="Signature-12345678" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#id-4453123">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>zYeQGz0jnyy3tI5gruq+IlGyzQo=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>m5fuzJnVOQGNsu4s2kfaI+UTReUSz9pMxH…=</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-98765432"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STRId-33454994" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Reference URI="#CertId-9502902" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

My question is how can I sign soap message in PHP? I guess there is some better way than just manually adding headers? I managed to sign xml document that is sent in envelopes body but I'm totally lost with signing the SOAP itself.

Comment: Could you tell a bit detailed gow did you solve this problem with: WSO2. Maybe could you post your client side code part?

Comment: I quit using WSO2 for quite a while ago. Problem was that when SOAP response grew big enough, log showed that it failed digest verification. As far as I know when browsing log files, whole soap body wasn't included for c14-canonicalization which caused verification error. But I can search my archives when I have time if you still looking for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 Web Services Framework for PHP solved my problem

Comment: did you implement signing of the payload (ApplicationRequest) with WSO2 as well? any source code to share about those? =)

Comment: I used xmlseclibs for signing the payload. Pretty easy to implement. Don't have access to those codes at the moment though :/

Comment: If it's not too much to ask could you take a look at code at http://pastebin.com/9tQ9EM15? It's stand-alone (excl. xmlseclibs/wse-php) DownloadFileList to Nordea with their test certs and ids. Whole package with certs, wse-php, xmlseclibs, Nordea WSDL and outputs @ http://www.kajala.com/temp/NordeaWSTest1.zip, I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong since I keep getting "Content signature invalid" error. I converted their .p12 file with openssl pkcs12 -in WSNDEA1234.p12 -nodes -out WSNDEA1234.pem and then split the result to separate files. Any help appreciated. :)

Comment: also, let me know if you are interested in doing some freelance work, my email is jani@kajala.com. I have very tight schedule in this and I feel I'm just banging my head against wall. :/

Comment: Don't really know if you're working with this one anymore but I did quick testing with self created ApplicationRequest. Issue was that your ApplicationRequest gets encoded twice. So on server side it gets decoded but it is still on base64 format. Invalid digital signature error is in my opinion so misleading in this case. I'm not sure if it is SoapClient itself which does encoding based on type defined in WSDL.